# Power BI: CALCULATE SUM but with several filters and joins?

Tags: filter, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns, calculated-field

I'm stuck now at some point.
Here's the situation:

The data:

| Offset Account Name | AccountNo | Amount | Purpose | Invoice Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer1 | 100 | 150$ | "Customer1/Blahblah" | Inv001 |
| Customer1 | 100 | 250$ | "Customer1/Meow" | Inv002 |
| Distributor1 | 200 | 100$ | "Customer1/Inv001" | Inv003 |
| Distributor1 | 200 | 150$ | "Customer1/Inv002" | Inv004 |
| Distributor1 | 200 | 50$ | "Customer1/Inv002" | Inv005 |

My Goal? According to the example I need to extract the "InvNoXXX" from the "Purpose" column, match the entries from "Invoice Number" and then calculate the sum.

The results of the "calculate sum" should be then:

| Offset Account Name | AccountNo | Amount | Purpose | Invoice Number | Distributor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer1 | 100 | **50**$ | "Customer1/Blahblah" | Inv001 | Distributor 1 |
| Customer1 | 100 | **50**$ | "Customer1/Blahblah" | Inv002 | Distributor 1 |

As you can see, the each amounts from the distributors have been summarized and then substracted from the according amount of the matched "Invoice Number" from each "Customer-Row". And as a bonus, I need to show the according distributor in an new column.

The Point is: The data is currently only imported from an excel file and I'm trying to calculate everything within Power BI. I know how to do it in SQL, but in Power BI I'm lost.

Any ideas? Is this even possible in Power BI?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see [ask]. You'll need to take a crack at it and ask a more specific question about your code. If this isn't a coding question it's off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, then you want to link the customer values to the distributor values?

I suggest you two create two querys from the data source with two filters on it (Transform Button when you import data).
Then you have two Tables looking like this:

Customer Table:

| Offset Account Name | AccountNo | Amount | Purpose | Invoice Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer1 | 100 | 150$ | "Customer1/Blahblah" | Inv001 |
| Customer1 | 100 | 250$ | "Customer1/Meow" | Inv002 |

Distributor Table:

| Offset Account Name | AccountNo | Amount | Purpose | Invoice Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Distributor1 | 200 | 100$ | "Customer1/Inv001" | Inv003 |
| Distributor1 | 200 | 150$ | "Customer1/Inv002" | Inv004 |
| Distributor1 | 200 | 50$ | "Customer1/Inv002" | Inv005 |

After that, create a new column in the Distributor Table, add the value from Purpose column and replace everything before '/'.

At the end you have to link the Invoice Number from the Customer table Column to your new created "Invoice Column" in the Distributor table in the model view.

Comment: Hi oeliger.

I've tried it at first with "RELATEDTABLE" which basically does the same. But at last it wasn't an good solution. Your suggestion works fine and it's defenitely the best practice! Thanks!

Comment: Hi DerKamiKatze, I'm happy to hear that this is working for you!
Please feel free to mark this answer as a solution ;)